# Struggling to get a random name generator to work

Tags: javascript, random, generator

Trying to get this below to generate a random name made up of two parts and pushed together, I need help making it so that it prints out to the screen and so that it will chose one of the three options every time as at the moment sometimes it chooses none. I'm new to JavaScript.

```js
const randomName = {
   prefix: ['Bramble', 'Lion', 'Owl'],
   suffix: ['Paw', 'Throat', 'Tail']
};

let firstHalf = () => {
switch(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)){
  case 0:
      console.log(randomName.prefix[0])
  break;
  case 1:
      console.log(randomName.prefix[1])
  break;
  case 2:
      console.log(randomName.prefix[2])
  break;
};
};

let secondHalf = () => {
switch(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)){
    case 0:
        console.log(randomName.suffix[0])
    break;
    case 1:
        console.log(randomName.suffix[1])
    break;
    case 2:
        console.log(randomName.suffix[2])
    break;
  };
};


console.log(`Your warrior name is ${firstHalf()} ${secondHalf()}!`);
```

Comment: Your switch case returns a number between 0 and 9. If you need a number between a min and a max value you should check: [Random number between two numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-number-between-two-numbers-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Simple way is create function which return one of the element of array without any case switch loops

```js
const randomName = {
   prefix: ['Bramble', 'Lion', 'Owl'],
   suffix: ['Paw', 'Throat', 'Tail']
};
function getRand(arr){
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)]
}
console.log(`Your warrior name is ${getRand(randomName.prefix)} ${getRand(randomName.suffix)}!`);
```

Comment: You are using `arr.length` to define wich maximum `index` can be choosen, but the maximum index is 1 less than the array length since the first index is 0.
using `Math.floor` will result in having very small chances of that happening but it can still happen if the output of `Math.random` is 1.

Comment: Shyne is incorrect.  The `Math.floor`  approach here will give a proper even distribution.

Comment: @Shyne please read documentation about [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) in this example you get from 0 to 2, that exactly what he need

Comment: My bad, i thought `Math.random` would return a number between 0 and 1 inclusive but 1 is excluded.

Answer (score 0):

`Math.random()` randomly picks in [0;1[
if you do x10 you end up with this range [0;10[
but you only have 3 values (indexes 0, 1 and 2) so when it picks 3 or above you end up with nothing picked.

You need to find a way to pick [0,3[ to make sure you have a value that correspond to your random number

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code:

1. `firstHalf` and `secondHalf` do not `return` anything.
2. Your `Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)` results in random numbers between `0` and `9`, while you have only `3` options. Replace that `10` with 3`. Or... use the array's length.
3. You don't need a `switch` statement if the condition of the switch is what you use:

```
switch(myNumber){
  case 0:
    doStuffWith[0];
  break;
  case 1:
    doStuffWith[1];
  break;
  case 2:
    doStuffWith[2];
  break;
};
```

Can be replaced with:

```
doStuffWith[myNumber]
```

So, that all together, `firstHalf` should probably be something like:

```
let firstHalf = () => {
  const name = randomName.prefix[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomName.prefix.length)];
  console.log('firstHalf', name);
  return name;
};
```

Comment: I think you intended to write `doStuffWith[1]` and `doStuffWith[2]`

Answer (score 0):

If you use a function which returns a number between a min and max you could do the following. Check the following link @Reyno mentioned in the comments to find a function like this:  [Generate random number between two numbers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-number-between-two-numbers-in-javascript)

As Cerbrus somehow already wrote:

If the function then only returns numbers which are represented in your name-arrays you don't need the switch case.

```
const randomName = {
  prefix: ['Bramble', 'Lion', 'Owl'],
  suffix: ['Paw', 'Throat', 'Tail']
};

firstHalf = randomName.prefix[randomNumberBetween(0, 3)];
secondHalf = randomName.suffix[randomNumberBetween(0, 3)];
```

Or to make it more relaiable use the length of your name arrays so you don't always have to change the max value if you add new names

```
const randomName = {
  prefix: ['Bramble', 'Lion', 'Owl'],
  suffix: ['Paw', 'Throat', 'Tail']
};

firstHalf = randomName.prefix[randomNumberBetween(0, randName.prefix.length)];
secondHalf = randomName.suffix[randomNumberBetween(0, randName.suffix.length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use npm, there’s a javascript library that allows you to generate random names (it’s pretty recent)

I only started using it because they have some pretty good settings tbh

You’ll just need to install it using npm “npm install nameforgejs”. I don’t know if they’ll make it possible to use without npm

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35295066)

Answer (score -1):

you are doing it wrong, don't use switch statements and individually coding each value, that's very bad practice.
now, your random function is wrong too, you want a integer between 0 and 2 and generate a FLOAT between 0 and 10.
here is what you should do to generate your random number:

```
function random(min, max) {
    let delta = max - min;
    return min+Math.round(Math.random()*delta);
}
```

and to get a random value in an array you can do this:

```
let firstHalf = randomName.prefix[random(0, randomName.prefix.length-1)];
```

Comment: `Math.floor` was perfectly fine. In fact, your `Math.Round` can result in numbers 1 higher than `max`.

Comment: `Math.round` cannot result in numbers 1higher than max.

example with 2 as min and 5as max and random value being the maximum:

delta = 5 - 2 = 3 
 | 
return value = 2 + 1*3 = 5

rounding 5 will always result in 5.

And `Math.floor` will prevent us from having the max value and probabilities of having the different numbers won't be equal.

Comment: Incorrect. The `Math.round` approach is in fact the one that gives an [uneven distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7377769/1835379)

Comment: After checking the link you sent i still can tell you that `math.floor` is uneven because if you have a range of [0, 100] 0 will have more chances of being picked than 100. and if you use `Math.round` they have the same chances of being picked.

Comment: Take this scenario: `Math.random() * 10`. If that rolls `0.0`, then the resulting `0.0` will floor to `0`. If that rolls `0.99`, then the resulting `9.9` will floor to `9`. That's a perfect _inclusive_ range of `10` integers, from `0` to `9`. You're getting confused by the fact that the `floor` approach is zero-based.

Comment: ok, `floor` don't confuse me at all, i just thought that `Math.random` sent back an number between 0 and 1 inclusive but as @Greg-- pointed out, it is excluded my bad, but using Math.round will still not generate numbers above max, though.